# Does continuous validation of a string possible with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a continuous validation on a string that contain a single special character also in the middle. Continuous validation means that even the partial string should return true.

By taking an example of a string like [four digits][a hyphen][three alphanumeric]

Cases
1) 1 Should validate 
2) 432 Should validate 
3) 1234- should validate 
4) 1q21- Should not validate 
5) 4532-a3s should validate 
6) 8023-as12 should not validate

the regex i have now is

```
/^([0-9]{1,4})?\-([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3})?$/;
```

This does not validate case 1 and 2 from the above listing

It does validate case 3, 4, 5, 6 from above cases

Comment: Can `1-2a` be `true` ? I think it should give `false`

Comment: would `1234ab` match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the first group not optional followed by an optional hyphen and make the group non capturing if you don't need it. If you want to match only digits as well, you could use an alternation.

```
^(?:\d+|[0-9]{4}-?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3})?)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]{4}-?` Match 4 digits with optional `-`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}` Match any of the listed in the character class 1 - 3 times
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DUc2iO/2)

If there are no more than 4 digits are allowed and the hyphen should be there in the second part you could also use:

```
^(?:\d{1,4}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})?|\d{4})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WYxbRH/1)

Comment: Thanks for the input.. this does not true for the case 3, and validates strings like 12d which is not supposed to be ..

Comment: your update improved the validation .. thanks .. but it also validates strings starting like 1b2, 1df3 which is not supposed to be as the first four contains alphabets also

Comment: your update on regex101 worked .. thanks .. if you can update here someone can mark your answer as accepted answer

Comment: This will match `5555555555555` (unlimited digits) and `5555qqq` (no hyphen).

Comment: @Amadan I see, I have added another pattern to the answer in case that is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
^(\d{1,3}|\d{4}(-[a-z0-9]{0,3})?)$
```

<kbd>[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DUc2iO/5)</kbd> (explanation included)

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for pointing out, updated! (anyways, that was not mentioned by op)

Comment: This will match `1-a`, and will not match `1234-`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use simple javascript to solve this problem. You loop through each character, check to see in which index range they fall in and apply validation there accordingly.

```js
function validateString(str){
   if(str.length > 8 || str.length == 0) return false;
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;++i){
      if(i < 4){
          if(!(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9')) return false;            
        }else if(i == 4){
         if(str.charAt(i) != '-')  return false;           
        }else{
           if(!(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9' || str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z' || str.charAt(i) >= 'A' && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z')) return false;
        }
    }  
      
    return true;
}
  const tests = [
 '1',
    '432',
    '1234-',
    '1q21-',
    '4532-a3s',
    '8023-as12',
    '1-2a',
    '1234ab',
    '1-a',
    '5555555555555',
    '5555qqq',
    '1234-@#@'
];
  
  
 tests.forEach((value) => {
     console.log(value + " => " + validateString(value));
 });
```

Comment: This is incorrect implementation of the pattern - you *only* consider `-` in the fourth position, whereas it could appear in second or third, depending on the amount of digits in front of it. In general, you also *only* correctly considers input of length `8` for validity. Technically, the code doesn't explicitly say that but at length, say, 7 the checks for positions are really rigid and a pattern of `123-a3s` would fail. A pattern of `1234-a3` would succeed but it stands that at length 7, there are false negatives.

Comment: @VLAZ OP asked for  `[four digits][a hyphen][three alphanumeric]`. I'd agree with you on the part you say this is very rigid.

Comment: @UlysseBN the pattern supplied says 1-4 starting digits. It's implied that the requirement is actually *up to* four digits. The accepted answer confirms this but it's not really surprising as the information is already in the question.

Comment: OK, so apparently the accepted answer was changed. I guess the requirement really was "only four digits". In light of this I concede that the requirement is unclear.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, OP specified this format `[four digits][a hyphen][three alphanumeric] `. So, I assuming if a hyphen comes, it has to come at the 4th position and not before or after that.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, the requirement is a bit confusing.

Comment: @vivek_23 quite confusing, actually now that I re-examine it. The list of valid/invalid cases doesn't at all clarify stuff like `1-a` for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something regex is particularly good at, but...

```
^(?:\d{1,3}|\d{4}(?:-([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3}))?)$
```

You have to incrementally build parts, with satisfied parts being fully stated and mandatory, and unsatisfied parts at the end optional.

Answer (score 0):

Some trick could be to have a regex only for the complete version, say:

```
/^\d{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}$/
```

Have a full correct pattern:

```
"1234-aA0"
```

And fulfill user input with the correct pattern before regex check:

```js
const detect = function (userInput) {
  if (userInput.length > 8) return false

  const regex = /^\d{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}$/
  const pattern = "1234-aA0"
  
  return regex.test(userInput + pattern.slice(userInput.length))
}

const tests = ['1', '432', '1234-', '1q21-', '4532-a3s', '8023-as12', '1-2a', '1234ab', '1-a', '5555555555555', '5555qqq', '1234-@#@']
  
  
tests.forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value + " => " + detect(value));
});
```